# UseEffect - else with curly brackets causing error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Basically, the else with curly brackets is causing the error.
If if the else clause is `else handleshow(false)` then there is no error. Why are the curly braces in the else statement causing the error?

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        handleShow(true);
      } else {
        handleShow(false);
      }
      // correct code: else handleshow(false);
    });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll');
    };
  }, []);
```

The error output

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/daway/React Practice Folder/netflix-clone/src/Nav.js:13
  10 |     } else handleShow(false);
  11 |   });
  12 |   return () => {
> 13 |     window.removeEventListener('scroll');
     | ^  14 |   };
  15 | }, []);
  16 | return (
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:8070:18
  8067 | function callCallback() {
  8068 |   didCall = true;
  8069 |   restoreAfterDispatch();
> 8070 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
       |        ^  8071 |   didError = false;
  8072 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  8073 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the `else` that's failing. You're missing an argument in your `removeEventListener`.

[removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: The problem is with the curly braces in the else statement. The error goes away when I remove the curly braces, which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the listener you want to remove from the event.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const listener = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 100) {
        handleShow(true);
      } else {
        handleShow(false);
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listener);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', listener);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. It asks to remove the callback function as well. The confusing thing is why does it not ask to remove the the callback function, when the curly braces on the else part is removed? Is the callback function not a callback function anymore if the curly braces are removed which should not be the case.

Comment: well, that's kinda odd :D idk what to do sorry

Comment: Defining the callback function outside the use-effect hook and specifiying the callback function in the removeListener solved  the issue. Maybe it is a bad practice to define if-else statement inside a use-effect hook.